# Are objects inside a static list eligible for garbage collection?

Tags: java, static, garbage-collection

I know that static variables are not eligible for garbage collection for as long as the class is loaded but i was wondering if that is the same case for it's object contents. I have this static List which contains a class object references. Are "someObject" eligible for garbage collection if no one's referencing them?

```
private static List<SomeObject> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I didn’t get that. It `myList` contains a `SomeObject`, that it is referring to it.

Comment: If they're in a static list, they're being referenced.

Comment: What exactly would you expect from the garbage collector? Calling `remove` on the `List`? That’s not, how garbage collection works. The garbage collector does not modify objects. The validity of, e.g. `myList.get(0).someAction();`, does not change. In other words, a question like this should not arise at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if that is the same case for it's object contents.

Yes, it is the same for the object's contents.  And their contents.  And their contents ... etcetera.

An object is reachable if some part of your application *could* try to access it at some point in the future.

Or another way to put it (in practice<sup>1</sup>) is that an object is reachable if there is a *path* to it via a chain of references, starting at a GC root.  Static variables are GC roots, as are thread stacks.

---

> Are "someObject" eligible for garbage collection if no one's referencing them?

If an object is in a list, it is referenced by the list.  If the list is reachable, then so are its contents.

---

<sup>1 - In theory, a compiler *could* determine that while a path exists to an object, in reality the path is never going to be followed.  However, that requires some difficult / expensive analysis by the compiler.  So this is an optimization approach that typically doesn't get tried, except in limited cases; e.g. when a variable that is in scope is not going to be used again.</sup>

Comment: Note that there are restrictions for the possible optimizations on unused heap variables when the garbage collection would be observable. So even in that hypothetical case, you wouldn’t notice, as the program behavior doesn’t change.

Comment: *".... as the program behavior doesn’t change."* - Apart from OOME's !!

Comment: You mean the hypothetical prevention of OOMEs, as we’re still talking about the reclamation of objects that doesn’t happen in practice. If a program works as intended in a specific configuration, adding that optimization wouldn’t change that.

Comment: No.  I mean that if a program crashes due to an OOME, that is an observable event.  Albeit not one that is (necessarily) observable within the application itself.  The fact that the user will notice the app crashing (!!) means that it is significant whether or not the optimization is implemented.  (I'm not saying that is *should* be ...)

Comment: You can not track an OOME to the absence of a particular single optimization as its cause. Besides that, the presence of a particular optimization is not guaranteed, but the statement of my first comment was that this specific optimization would only be allowed if its presence does not change the behavior of a program, except for the possible prevention of an OOME that would happen without. The question whether a JVM vendor can legally add a particular optimization, is entirely different to the question whether an application developer should rely on the presence of a particular optimization.

Comment: *"... but the statement of my first comment was that this specific optimization would only be allowed if its presence does not change the behavior of a program, **except for the possible prevention of an OOME that would happen without**."* - Thanks for acknowledging my point.

Comment: "You can not track an OOME to the absence of a particular single optimization as its cause." - I don't think you can make that as a general statement.  For certain applications, in certain circumstances you probably can.

Comment: There is an infinite number of potential optimizations which have never been implemented. It would be presumptuous to claim to know that definitely only one of them would solve a particular memory insufficiency, but no other could. But I don’t want to discuss this further, as it is completely missing the point. As already said, my first comment was about the legality of an optimization. Whether a particular execution environment has enough memory or not, hence whether OOMEs may occur, is an implementation detail, completely outside the specification.